# dynamic, linq and Select()

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, c#-4.0

Considering the following (pointless, but it's for illustration purpose) test class :

```
public class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWontCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
    {
        return t.Select(x => ToStr(x));
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWillCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();

        foreach (var d in t)
        {
            res.Add(ToStr(d));
        }

        return res;
    }

    public string ToStr(dynamic d)
    {
        return new string(d.GetType());
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it compile with the following error, on `t.Select(x => ToStr(x))` ?

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' 
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion 
exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

No error on the second method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what happens here is that since the expression `ToStr(x)` involves a `dynamic` variable, the whole expression's result type is also `dynamic`; that's why the compiler thinks that it has an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` where it expects an `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWontCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
{
    return t.Select(x => ToStr(x));
}
```

There are two ways you can fix this.

**Use an explicit cast:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWontCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
{
    return t.Select(x => (string)ToStr(x));
}
```

This tells the compiler that the result of the expression is definitely going to be a string, so we end up with an `IEnumerable<string>`.

**Replace the lambda with a method group:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWontCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
{
    return t.Select(ToStr);
}
```

This way the compiler implicitly converts the method group expression to a lambda. Note that since there is no mention of the `dynamic` variable `x` in the expression, the type of its result can be immediately inferred to be `string` because there is only one method to consider, and its return type is `string`.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and in particular for the Method Group version

Answer (score 3):

it would appear that the C# compiler is determining the type of the lambda in the first method `x => ToStr(x)` as `Func<dynamic, dynamic>` and therefore declaring the type of the `IEnumerable` returned as `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.  A small change `x => (string)ToStr(x)` seems to fix it.

This is most likely because of type inference rules - because if you change the line to this:

```
return t.Select<dynamic, string>(x => ToStr(x));
```

It compiles without error.

The specific type inference rule in question, however, I'm not too sure of - however if you take this code:

```
public void foo(dynamic d)
{
  var f = this.ToStr(d);
  string s = f;
}
```

And then hover over the 'f' in the editor you will see that intellisense reports the type of the expression as 'dynamic f'.  This will be because the `this.ToStr(d)` is a dynamic expression, regardless of whether the method itself, and its return type, is known at compile time.

The compiler then is happy to assign `string s = f;` because it is able to statically analyse the type that `f` is likely to be, because ultimately `ToStr` always returns a string.

This is why ths first method requires a cast or explicit type parameters - because the compiler is making `ToStr` be of `dynamic` type; because it has at least one dynamic expression as part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWontCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
{
    return t.Select(ToStr);
}
```

Another possibility is to specify explicitly the generic arguments:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ToEnumerableStrsWontCompile(IEnumerable<dynamic> t)
{
    return t.Select<dynamic, string>(x => ToStr(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  `return t.Select(x => ToStr(x)) as IEnumerable<string>`